# Laravel Eloquent collection sortBy not taking effect

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, eloquent

After eager loading attributes and their items I tried to sort the attributes without of luck.

```
public function __invoke(Category $category)
    {
        $category->load(['attributes']);

        $category->attributes->load(['items' => function ($query) use ($category) {
            $query->whereHas('productVariations.product.categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('categories.id', $category->id);
            });
        }]);
        foreach ($category->attributes as $attribute) {
            $attribute->items = $attribute->items->sortByDesc('name');
        }

        dump($category->attributes->first()->items->pluck('name')); // Items are sorted
        dd($category->attributes->toArray()); // Items are not sorted
     }
```

Can you please tell me why is that and how can I sort them with collections (not Eloquent and MySql)?

Comment: Works for me on https://implode.io/ with `stdClass`. See [sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY4PJ.png)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks again, I think this problem related to Laravel Eloquent collection

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not replacing the items in the collection itself. So I believe a `map` will do a better job here than a traditional `foreach`. So try this instead and let me know:

```
$attributes = $category->attributes->map(function($attribute) {
  $attribute->items = $attribute->items->sortByDesc('name');
  return $attribute;
});

dd($attributes);
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work, I also add `&` to the attribute but still not working